# Travis build with R failing on file download

Tags: r, ftp, travis-ci

I'm using Travis-CI to create an R build that requires a file download from a remote URL to a temporary location.  This works fine on my local machine (Windows 10), but fails when it's run on Travis.

I have an R build file that creates a temporary file location, downloads a file from a remote URL, reads the file, and then removes the temporary file.

```
tmp <- tempfile()
url <- "ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/README.TXT"
download.file(url, tmp, quiet = TRUE)
lines <- readLines(tmp)
file.remove(tmp)
```

My Travis YAML file sources this build file and is meant to push a commit to GitHub when the file is downloaded successfully (using encryption).

```
language: r
sudo: false
cache: packages
git:
  depth: false
script:
- Rscript -e 'source("build.R")'
- git config --global user.name "fawda123"
- git config --global user.email "mbafs2012@gmail.com"
- git pull https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}.git HEAD:${TRAVIS_BRANCH}
- git add -A
- git commit -a -m "New download via travis-ci.org [ci skip]"
- git push https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}.git HEAD:${TRAVIS_BRANCH}
notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
    - mbafs2012@gmail.com
    on_success: change
    on_failure: change
env:
  global:
  - TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG=fawda123/travis-test
  - TRAVIS_BRANCH=master
  - CRAN: http://cran.rstudio.com
  - secure: 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
```

The build fails on Travis when trying to connect to the remote URL with `download.file()`. Travis returns this error (full build log [here](https://travis-ci.org/github/fawda123/travis-test/builds/682919079)):

```
$ Rscript -e 'source("build.R")'
Error in download.file(url, tmp, quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/README.TXT'
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> download.file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, tmp, quiet = TRUE) :
  downloaded length 0 != reported length 4259
2: In download.file(url, tmp, quiet = TRUE) :
  cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/README.TXT': FTP status was '425 Cannot open data connection'
Execution halted
```

Seems Travis has issues connecting to a remote URL, is there something I'm missing?  I've tried this with different URLs, so it's not specific to the one in the example.  Full GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/fawda123/travis-test).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I seem to have the same issue with an ftp link. Is it possible that downloads from ftp links are blocked?

Comment: No, but I've switched all of my CI workflows to GitHub Actions.  They seem to work much better.

Comment: Was a good idea, switched now too and works much better.